# Can't locate object method "object_file" via package

Tags: perl

When i am installing Params:Validate on my linux server i am getting below error
Can't locate object method "object_file" via package "ExtUtils::CBuilder" at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/Module/Build/Base.pm line 3935

But i have installed latest version of ExtUtils::CBuilder. Any idea which version of ExtUtils::CBuilder is compatible

Comment: can you add more details like which OS, way you are trying to install etc?

Comment: OS is SUSE LINUX, Downloaded the binaries from online and below steps are executed
perl Build.PL
Checking whether your kit is complete...
Looks good

Checking prerequisites...
Looks good

Deleting Build
Removed previous script 'Build'

Creating new 'Build' script for 'Params-Validate' version '1.24'

Server1:/tmp/Params-Validate-1.24 # ./Build
Can't locate object method "object_file" via package "ExtUtils::CBuilder" at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/Module/Build/Base.pm line 3935

Answer (score 0):

To install Params::Validate, simply copy and paste either of the commands in to your terminal(Need internet).

cpanm

```
                cpanm Params::Validate
```

CPAN shell

```
                perl -MCPAN -e shell
                install Params::Validate
```